# Unable to fetch the updated Data in hbase through pig after storing using HbaseStorage function?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig, apache-phoenix

I am new to pig Scripting . I am unable to fetch the data which i have stored through pig script into hbase using HbaseStorage(). But when i am trying to fetch the data using phoenix i am able to see the data .

Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the code you are using for storage and retrieval?

Comment: I was using the minTimeStamp and maxTimeStamp guyz for fetching the records.

Answer (score 0):

The problem Solved guyz . As the timeStamp always changes for a column in Hbase. When i use the Stored Time correctly over there for searching . I was able to fetch the records .

Previously i was using intial row creation timeStamp for searching.